# I Must Ask You This

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I loiter around all day,
>
> Until you kick me out for the week,
>
> You may invite me back in until I've evened out.
>
> I will always be back to linger your way,
>
> Gruff, big, small, and chic,
>
> Those are all forms of me, no doubt!
>
> Near a parenthesis like thing, I lay.
>
> And cutting edge technology, a nemesis name it reek(s).
>
> Lastly, I just sit here waiting for every scrap that doesn't find its route.

What am I?

Comment: Interesting Riddle (+1) :D

Comment: Thought 1: Backpack  Thought 2: Garbage Can

Comment: you pronounce 'route' as 'rowt' not 'root' then? does ABCABCABC have an official rhyme name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are:

> Facial Hair

I loiter around all day,

> Doesn't really do anything for you

Until you kick me out for the week,

> You might trim your facial hair once a week

You may invite me back in until I've evened out.

I will always be back to linger your way,

> You can even it out, but then it grows back and gets in the way.

Gruff, big, small and chic,
Those are all forms of me, no doubt!

> Different styles of facial hair.

Near a parenthesis like thing, I lay.

> Your mouth. Has a slight curve to it and it opens and closes.

And cutting edge technology, a nemesis name it reek(s).

> Cutting edge technology is a pun, not sure about the second part.

Lastly, I just sit here waiting for every scrap that doesn't find its route.

> Food crumbs could get stuck in your beard/mustache if they miss your mouth.

Title:

> I "mustache" you this

Comment: Great! Your second guess is correct! :D

Comment: If you need guidance for the rest of it just ask for a hint :)

Comment: I think I could use a hint on the "a nemesis name it reek(s)" part. Is everything else right? @QuantumTwinkie

Comment: That part just refers to rot13(Vg vf gur rarzl orpnhfr vg funirf n zhfgnpur be orneq.) :D

Comment: Also, the title is a hint too, but that's all :) well done!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Haha, I didn't even notice the hint in the title. I like it!

Answer (score 3):

Are you..

> Litter?

I loiter around all day,

> litter lies around. 'loiter' is also very close to 'litter'

Until you kick me out for the week,

> The weekly garbage disposal

You may invite me back in till I've evened out.
I will always be back to linger your way,

> You'll soon have litter again

Gruff, big, small and chic,
Those are all forms of me, no doubt!

> Litter can have many forms, almost anything can become litter at some point

Near a parenthesis like thing, I lay.

> maybe the skip, or the trashcan?

And cutting edge technology, a nemesis name it reek(s).

> Twitter? I don't see how this is a nemesis though.. Litter surely reeks.

Lastly, I just sit here waiting for every scrap that doesn't find its route.

> If new scrap misses the trash can ("doesn't find it's route"), it becomes litter by definition.

Comment: Sorry incorrect :) +1

Answer (score 1):

partial:

> Oddball

Until you kick me out for the week,

> Balls can be kicked

You may invite me back in till I've evened out.

> In order to 'even out' you have to be 'odd'

Comment: Sorry incorrect, :) +1